# Put a file on FTP site with contents from string variable (no local file)

Tags: php, ftp

I want to upload a file to an FTP server, but the file content is held in a variable, not in an actual local file. I want to avoid using a file; this is to avoid security risks when dealing with sensitive data on a (possibly) not-so-secure system<sup>(*)</sup>, as well as to minimize the (already low) overhead of file handling.

But PHP's FTP API only offers uploading files from local files via the function [`ftp_put`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) or (when the file is already opened as a file handle) [`ftp_fput`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fput.php).

Currently, I use this function with a temporary file in which I write the contents before the upload:

```
$tmpfile = tmpfile();
fwrite($tmpfile, $content);
fseek($tmpfile, 0);
ftp_fput($ftp, $filename, $tmpfile, FTP_BINARY);
```

**Is there a simpler way without using files on the local (PHP) site at all?**

There is [`ftp_raw`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-raw.php) which can be used to send arbitrary commands, so I could issue the `PUT` command manually, however I don't see a way to manually write the data on the data channel...

I don't know if it is important, but the FTP connection is secured with SSL ([`ftp_ssl_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php)).

---

<sup>(*) Consider the scenario where an attacker has read-only control over the entire file system.</sup>

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This may be no ultimate solution but I guess is still better than the original approach:

You can avoid temporary files on the file system by using a **PHP memory stream**. It basically is a file handle wrapper which (behind the scenes) uses no actual file but instead some chunk of memory.

So virtually you still use a **file handle** (so `ftp_fput` is happy), but no actual **file** (so no file is written to the disk and the overhead is kept minimal).

```
$tmpfile = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
fputs($tmpfile, $content);
rewind($tmpfile); // or fseek
```

Note that when uploading multiple files, you can further minimize overhead by reusing the same file handle for all files (unless you parallelize the procedure, of course). In this case, also rewind the file after `ftp_fput` as well as truncate it using `ftruncate($tmpfile, 0)`.

Comment: Why isn't this the ultimate solution, is this because it's sort of hacky, or because this creates risks?

Comment: @Martijn Well, to me it just sounds hacky - no security concerns. I was looking for something like `ftp_puts` (put data from a string argument), which doesn't seem to exist. In general, the protocol "wrapper" api of PHP allows to circumvent such missing API functionality, which sounds hacky to me but seems to be the "normal" way to do something with "imaginary" files, when some other API only offers handling files such as the FTP API. Someone might find it elegant, someone else finds it hacky. ;)

Comment: How would you send the file name with this?

Comment: @user2924019 In the ftp command you invoke afterwards, you always explicitly give the remote file name. This is true for this solution as well as when specifying a file name to upload.

Answer (score 4):

With no local file involved (ftp_fput):

```
$stream = fopen('php://memory','r+');
fwrite($stream, $newFileContent);
rewind($stream);

$success = ftp_fput($connectionId, "remoteFileName", $stream, FTP_BINARY);

fclose($stream);
```

Comment: Not working -> Warning: ftp_put() expects parameter 3 to be a valid path

Answer (score 2):

fopen should be able to connect via ftp:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

and then use fwrite to write string to connection:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Second parameter of fwrite is string that need to be written - you don't need file there.

Answer (score 2):

-----FTP PUT contents (php 7.0) ---

```
$tmpFile = tmpfile();

fwrite($tmpFile, $contents);
rewind($tmpFile);

$tmpMetaData = stream_get_meta_data($tmpFile);

if (ftp_put($ftpObj, $remoteFile, $tmpMetaData['uri'], FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "fail";
}

fclose($tmpFile);
```