# Creating a CSV file on a remote FTP server

Tags: php, csv, ftp

I want to create a CSV file in a remote server in a certain folder. I have the FTP details, and the code for creating the CSV ready, but my problem is I am unable to save that CSV in that remote server. I used below code to connect to FTP:

```
$ftp_server = "127.0.0.1";      // FTP Server Address (exlucde ftp://)
$ftp_user_name = "username";    // FTP Server Username
$ftp_user_pass = "password";    // Password

// Connect to FTP Server
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
// Login to FTP Server
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
```

Now I want to save the file to the connection made above.

Currently below is the code that i used to open a csv stream.

```
$structure = './orderexport/'.$order_date;
if (!mkdir($structure, 0777, true)) {
    $filename = "orderexport/".$order_date."/test_".$order_id.".csv";
} else{
    $filename = "orderexport/".$order_date."/test_".$order_id.".csv";   
}

$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
```

Is there anything I need to do on csv end too to save it to remote server?

Comment: are you trying to create a folder on remote ?

Comment: actually i want to create a file inside that particular directory

Comment: You also need to check permissions and make sure the folder is here (and create it if not).

Comment: yes done that see above code(second snippet) but it is creating the folder in the same server not the remote server.How can i do same in remote server?

Comment: Another option is [Put a file on FTP site with contents from string variable (no local file)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31075417/850848).

Comment: Or [Transfer in-memory data to FTP server without using intermediate file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27103587/850848)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for your reference ( Code not tested , just make use of `ftp_mkdir()` & `ftp_put()` )

```
$ftp_server = "127.0.0.1";      // FTP Server Address (exlucde ftp://)
$ftp_user_name = "username";     // FTP Server Username
$ftp_user_pass = "password";      // Password

// Connect to FTP Server
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
// Login to FTP Server
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

$structure = './orderexport/'.$order_date;

if (ftp_mkdir($ftp_conn, $structure )) {

    $filename = "orderexport/".$order_date."/test_".$order_id.".csv";
    ftp_put($conn_id, $filename, $file, FTP_ASCII);
    echo 'Success';
}
else{
    echo 'Error';
}
```

Comment: Pls define the variable `$file` (which should be the path to a file in the origin server.)

Comment: isn't there any function like fopen for ftp like ftp_open? or is there a way to achieve that.I directly like to save the generated csv to the server

Comment: I guess no, but this is the usual & recommended way when you want your files to save over FTP